# zero padding variable length of array in uproot

Tags: uproot

I need a memory efficient way to zero pad uneven array size per event according to largest array in a tree. Is there any way available to do that in uproot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
jagged_array.pad(max_length).fillna(0)
```

If you need to find the maximum, you can

```py
jagged_array.counts.max()
```

If you then need to turn it into pure NumPy, use `regular()`.